# How to assign currently selected drop-down list item to a label in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

In my asp.net web form application, I have used a drop-down list with values coming from the code behind. I want to assign the currently selected dropdownList item to a label in jQuery. Here is the dropdownList HTML:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCustomers" CssClass="ddlCustomers" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Enabled="true" >
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

I want to use a jQuery function for drop-down list text change within `document.ready()` or outside its scope to keep track of currently selected customer and assign its name to the label. Once I will assign the currently selected customer name to that label, I will have to show content on the page based on a selected customer. I have used the following code within `document.ready()` but it is not working.

```
              $("#ddlCustomers").change(function () {
                  var text = $('#ddlCustomers option:selected').text();

                  $('#lblCustName').text('Name =' + text);
              });
```

Is there any way to assign currently selected customer name to the label with ID lblCustName with jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Asp.Net server control id's tends to change when used with `ContentPlaceHolders`. Use ClientID when accessing server controls or add a new property `ClientIDMode` and set it's value to `Static`. This will not change the ID of server control at runtime.

```
$("#<%= ddlCustomers.ClientID %>").on('change', function() {
    var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();

    $('#<%= lblCustName.ClientID %>').text('Name =' + text);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Suprabhat it works for me but when the current dropdown text is assigned to the label, the page refreshes itself and the label value is lost again. Is there any solution for this, so that I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: Quiet a strange behavior. As I can see you have already used `AutoPostBack="false"` to stop postback.

Comment: Actually the purpose of this dropdownlist is to select data based on the currently selected customer, that's why the page is refreshing and I lost the label text.

Comment: What happens when you postback? Do you call a method or something?

Comment: I think if you trigger the `change` event immediately after wiring it up the handler, it should set the label to the currently selected value on page load. `$("#<%= ddlCustomers.ClientID %>").on('change', function() { ... }).change();`